# How do I get default border of JFrame component in BufferedImage data output?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to get surrounding border of JFrame component in my captured screenshot (Image data) using BufferedImage().

Currently I am doing this;

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

class getframeImageExample {

public static BufferedImage getImageData(
        Component component) {

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            component.getWidth(),
            component.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
    component.printAll( image.getGraphics() );
    return image;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final JFrame f = new JFrame("JFrame Border");
            f.setUndecorated(false);
            f.setLocation(500,300);
            f.setSize(560, 420);

            JMenuItem screenshot =
                    new JMenuItem("Take Snapshot");
            screenshot.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                            BufferedImage imageOutput = getImageData(f.getRootPane());
                            try {
                                // write the image as a PNG
                                ImageIO.write(
                                        imageOutput,
                                        "png",
                                        new File("CapturedImage.png"));
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } );
            JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
            menu.add(screenshot);
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.add(menu);
            f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
```

}

Please see attached png files for more details.

[Original JFrame window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05EI8.png) ; 
[Captured Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjFpp.png)

Comment: Works for me. What OS?

Comment: Isn't this obvious from pictures? Win 7 (worst case Vista;-]).

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Enterprise (64-bit.).

Comment: @EmilSierżęga  `Isn't this obvious from pictures? ` No.

Comment: I recommend posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exactly reproduces the problem - when I run similar code the original and captured are identical.

Comment: @copeg I've updated code sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to get surrounding border of JFrame component in my captured screenshot

Your code currently passes in the root pane of the JFrame, which does not contain the `JFrame` decorations. To get the `JFrame` decorations in the Image, pass in the `JFrame` instance. eg

```
BufferedImage imageOutput = getImageData(f);
```